# add additional directory to running watchdog python

Tags: python-3.x, watchdog

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class WatchHandle(PatternMatchingEventHandler):

    patterns = ['*.md', '*.rst']

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            pass #some action...

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            pass #some action...

def watch(folder_to_watch):

    observer = Observer()

    for path in folder_to_watch:
        observer.schedule(WatchHandle, path, recursive=True)
        self.observers_lst.append(observer)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(3)
    except:
        for ob in self.observers_lst:
            ob.stop()
    for ob in self.observers_lst:
        ob.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_to_watch = ['dir_1', 'dir_2']
    watch(folder_to_watch)
```

The above is sort of my code, it runs just fine. But I would like to add additional folder to the `folder_to_watch` list while it is running, or somehow turn off watchdog, add a folder and restart watch() again. Is there a good way of doing that?